# Prevent default order event on datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting, datatables

I have a server-side (ajax) processed datatable. I have enabled sorting on it but I want to implement my own custom sorting on it. I can capture the 'order.dt' event but I can't stop the event from making an ajax request (which reloads the data in the table).
Here's the code:

```
$('#resultTable')
        .on('order.dt', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();


            //Custom sorting logic (without making ajax request)
            return false;    
        })
        .dataTable(
            //Code to make ajax request
        );
```

Comment: How can you sort without reloading the data? Or do you just want to sort a single page of results?

Comment: Yeah, I only want to sort the single page of result, without making any server side processing (only on the client side) by manipulating the rows on the client side.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm attempting the same thing.

Comment: @maf748 no, i have tried all possible methods but nothing so far :(

Comment: @maf748 did you have a look at the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the sorting on datatables using `ordering: false` setting which creating the table.

I used a custom jQuery-based library [TableSorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) which gives the functionality of sorting the rows without firing an ajax request to update the page.

Hope it helps.